# QT based graphical application doesnt run properly in xfce without being root in a Docker container

Tags: docker, qt, ubuntu, containers

I have created two docker containers. In first docker container, I am installing Gnome desktop and in second one I installed XFCE desktop. In both containers, I am installing all the libraries related to QT5 with following lines:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.3.1-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu20.04    
USER root
    RUN apt-get -y install build-essential openssl libssl-dev libssl1.0 libgl1-mesa-dev libqt5x11extras5
    RUN dpkg -i <nameofapplicationIcannotshare>
    RUN groupadd guiusers
    RUN usermod -aG sudo guiuser
    RUN usermod -aG guiusers guiuser
    RUN echo "guiuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
```

In both containers the application is installed in /usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/AppName

I am running the container and connecting to it with TigerVNC (I have all necessary X11 server/VNC server related scripts installed in both containers and can connect without problems and can run all other non-QT applications without issue in both containers).

```
sudo docker run --name=QTApplication -e --runtime=nvidia --shm-size=9gb --privileged -e DISPLAY=0.0 -d --rm --tmpfs /run --tmpfs /run/lock --tmpfs /tmp --cap-add SYS_BOOT --cap-add SYS_ADMIN -v /home/ubuntu/omi:/home/guiuser/Documents/omi -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup -v /etc/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json:/etc/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json --gpus 'all,"capabilities=graphics,utility,display,video,compute"' -p 5901:5901 -p 6901:6901 -p 9988:9988 xfcecontainer:v1
```

In the case where Gnome desktop is installed, I can run the QT based GUI application while being the "guiuser" user and do not see any errors.
But when I run the application in xfce as guiuser, I see a ton of QT "warnings" and the application window shows up but it does not update (and the application hangs). The error log is attached: (When I run the application in xfce as root user the application works without errors). I want to run the application in xfce as guiuser as it interacts with other applications which must run as non-root.

```
WARNING: Qt message: Found metadata in lib /usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "linuxfb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QLinuxFbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


WARNING: Qt message: Found metadata in lib /usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/platforms/libqminimal.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


WARNING: Qt message: Found metadata in lib /usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/platforms/libqoffscreen.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


WARNING: Qt message: Found metadata in lib /usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


WARNING: Qt message: QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-matlab'
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/asam_c-api.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/boost.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/c-ares.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/cereal.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/clipper.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/cryptopp.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/doubleconversion.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/dtoa_c.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/forkfd.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/freetype2.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/g1fitting.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/geometrictools.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/giflib.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/glm.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/googlebreakpad.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/googletest.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/harfbuzz.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/iaccessible2.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/jasper.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/libcurl.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/libexpat.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/libjpeg.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/libkml.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/libmng.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/libpng.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/libtiff.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/libwebp.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/libxml2.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/MathWorksLicense.txt' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/minizip.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/netcdf.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/ogdi.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/opengl-headers.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/openjpeg.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/pcl.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/pcre2.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/pdal.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/penner-equations.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/physx.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/pixman.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/Poco.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/poly2tri.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/postgresql.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/prce2-jitcompiler.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/protobuf.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/qeventdispatcher-macos.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/qt.conf' is not an ELF object (file too small)
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/qtemporaryfile.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/sha-384-512.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/sha3-brg-endian.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/smoothscaling-imlib2.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/strtoll.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/text-codecs.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/thirdpartylicenses.txt' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/tinygltf.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/unicode.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/w3c-xml-schema.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/xcb.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: QElfParser: '/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/xkbcommon.rights' is not an ELF object
WARNING: Qt message: Found metadata in lib /usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-egl-integration.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.Xcb.QXcbGlIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.5",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb_egl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QXcbEglIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


WARNING: Qt message: Found metadata in lib /usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.Xcb.QXcbGlIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.5",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb_glx"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QXcbGlxIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


WARNING: Qt message: Found metadata in lib /usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/imageformats/libqgif.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "gif"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/gif"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QGifPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


WARNING: Qt message: Found metadata in lib /usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/imageformats/libqicns.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "icns"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/x-icns"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QICNSPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


WARNING: Qt message: Found metadata in lib /usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/imageformats/libqico.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "ico",
            "cur"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/vnd.microsoft.icon",
            "image/vnd.microsoft.icon"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QICOPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


WARNING: Qt message: Found metadata in lib /usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/imageformats/libqjpeg.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "jpg",
            "jpeg"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/jpeg",
            "image/jpeg"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QJpegPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


WARNING: Qt message: Found metadata in lib /usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/imageformats/libqpdf.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "pdf"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "application/pdf"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QPdfPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


WARNING: Qt message: Found metadata in lib /usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/imageformats/libqsvg.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "svg",
            "svgz"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/svg+xml",
            "image/svg+xml-compressed"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QSvgPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


WARNING: Qt message: Found metadata in lib /usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/imageformats/libqtga.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "tga"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/x-tga"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QTgaPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


WARNING: Qt message: Found metadata in lib /usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/imageformats/libqtiff.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "tiff",
            "tif"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/tiff",
            "image/tiff"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QTiffPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


WARNING: Qt message: Found metadata in lib /usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/imageformats/libqwbmp.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wbmp"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/vnd.wap.wbmp"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWbmpPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


WARNING: Qt message: Found metadata in lib /usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/imageformats/libqwebp.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "webp"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/webp"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWebpPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


WARNING: Qt message: QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "/usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/imageformats/libqpdf.so" : "Cannot load library /usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/imageformats/libqpdf.so: (libQt5Pdf.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)"
WARNING: Qt message: Found metadata in lib /usr/local/QTApplication_V1/bin/glnxa64/iconengines/libqsvgicon.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QIconEngineFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "svg",
            "svgz",
            "svg.gz"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QSvgIconPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


WARNING: Qt message: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 2 (BadValue), sequence: 435, resource id: 0, major code: 151 (Unknown), minor code: 24
```

I have tried to install the application in xfce as the "guiuser" user, but I get error that I need sudo privileges.

Somehow I think this is related to permissions for the QT plugin libraries in xfce ... but not sure.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: A Docker container normally runs a single process.  It sounds like you're trying to run a full desktop environment; would a virtual machine be a better match for your needs?

Comment: When I do "docker run", I can specify a -batch or -vnc option. -vnc is used only for setting up the application and then commit the container (no other way atm). -batch is used for GUI-less deployment to cloud for various "headless" uses. Besides, I see this issue in headless mode as well, because the application (not in my control) needs these QT libraries somewhere to function.